# Bad Orientation of Principal Axis of a Point Cloud

Tags: axis, pca, point-cloud-library, ros, point-clouds

I'm trying to calculate the principal axis via principal component analysis. I have a pointcloud and use for this the Point Cloud Library (pcl). Furthermore, I try to visualize the principal axis I calculated in rviz with markers. Here is the code snipped I use:

```
void computePrincipalAxis(const PointCloud& cloud, Eigen::Vector4f& centroid, Eigen::Matrix3f& evecs, Eigen::Vector3f& evals) {
  Eigen::Matrix3f covariance_matrix;
  pcl::computeCovarianceMatrix(cloud, centroid, covariance_matrix);
  pcl::eigen33(covariance_matrix, evecs, evals);
}

void createArrowMarker(Eigen::Vector3f& vec, int id, double length) {
  visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
  marker.header.frame_id = frameId;
  marker.header.stamp = ros::Time();
  marker.id = id;
  marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
  marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
  marker.pose.position.x = centroid[0];
  marker.pose.position.y = centroid[1];
  marker.pose.position.z = centroid[2];
  marker.pose.orientation.x = vec[0];
  marker.pose.orientation.y = vec[1];
  marker.pose.orientation.z = vec[2];
  marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  marker.scale.x = length;
  marker.scale.y = 0.02;
  marker.scale.z = 0.02;
  marker.color.a = 1.0;
  marker.color.r = 1.0;
  marker.color.g = 1.0;
  marker.color.b = 0.0;
  featureVis.markers.push_back(marker);
}

Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
Eigen::Matrix3f evecs;
Eigen::Vector3f evals;

// Table is the pointcloud of the table only.
pcl::compute3DCentroid(*table, centroid); 
computePrincipalAxis(*table, centroid, evecs, evals);

Eigen::Vector3f vec;

vec << evecs.col(0);
createArrowMarker(vec, 1, evals[0]);

vec << evecs.col(1);
createArrowMarker(vec, 2, evals[1]);

vec << evecs.col(2);
createArrowMarker(vec, 3, evals[2]);

publish();
```

This results in the following visualization:

[image: Segmented scene with table's principal axis.]

I'm aware that the scale is not very perfect. The two longer arrows are much too long. But I'm confused about a few things:

1. I think the small arrow should go either up, or downwards.
2. What does the value orientation.w of the arrow's orientation mean?

Do you have some hints what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orientations are represented by [Quaternions](http://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/) in ROS, not by directional vectors. Quaternions can be a bit unintuitive, but fortunately there are some [helper functions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Data%20Types#Helper_Functions) in the `tf` package, to generate quaternions, for example, from roll/pitch/yaw-angles.

One way to fix the marker would therefore be, to convert the direction vector into a quaternion.

In your special case, there is a much simpler solution, though: Instead of setting origin and orientation of the arrow, it is also possible to define start and end point (see [ROS wiki about marker types](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Arrow_.28ARROW.3D0.29)).  So instead of setting the `pose` attribute, just add start and end point to the  `points` attribute:

```
float k = 1.0; // optional to scale the length of the arrows

geometry_msgs::Point p;
p.x = centroid[0];
p.y = centroid[1];
p.z = centroid[2];
marker.points.push_back(p);
p.x += k * vec[0];
p.y += k * vec[1];
p.z += k * vec[2];
marker.points.push_back(p);
```

You can set `k` to some value < 1 to reduce the length of the arrows.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the orientation problem. I have another question though. The values of my axis vectors are small ( < 1). For my centroid also all values are < 1. But the axis I plot are massive in length. I thought they should all be short, first because I have small values, second because I thought only the eigenvalue defines the length of the eigenvectors (btw., I changed the scale.x = length to a fixed value now).

It's even the same if I do it for the coke can on the table (the bluish object). One axis is short and the other two seem to be infinite.

Comment: @Chris: When using start and end point, the `scale.x`-attribute specifies the diameter of the arrow, not its length (the length is implicitly given by the points). I don't see a reason why you are getting so large arrows, however. You can try to reduce the length setting `k` to a smaller value (see edit above).

Comment: @Chris: Have you checked what values are finally published (you can doo this using `rostopic echo /topic_name`)? Are they still < 1?

Comment: Not more then 1.79 in z axis when I listen to the topic. I think in rviz the unit 1 should correspond to one meter visually. Scaling would not solve the problem of course, I would like to really get rid of it. But I'll try to figure it and then add it here. If you have another idea keep me posted. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: I am clueless too, right now, but good luck! :). Of course scaling is only a workaround. Assuming, that the grid in your image has cell size=1, the arrows should indeed not be that big.